Help center page on deleted answers still links to old, broken GPT policy page
The help center page on deleted answers still links to a help center article, /help/gpt-policy, that was deleted last October:

[...] Answers copied from language learning models such as ChatGPT may also be removed even if they are attributed correctly.

The link needs to be changed to point to /help/gen-ai-policy.
This was previously done for another help center article, but I found another one where it wasn't done.

... or rather than removing obsolete pages, make them redirect to their replacement. Then the problem becomes much smaller as you'd only need to cleanup old links rather than broken links...

Also, the terminology "language learning models" is incorrect (it is probably a misunderstanding of "LLM", which stands for "large language model"); it should probably be something like "generative artificial intelligence tools" (as the new policy page phrases it).

@Gimby Per the comments on the answer there, the admin who deleted the page forgot they could redirect pages at the time, and then declined to do so because traffic logs in the dozens of hours proceeding the removal showed low hits.
